# How to parse web page in memory

Tags: parsing, html

Here is what I want to accomplish:

I need to write a utility that will be launched from the command line to extract some data from a web page. The content of the page is dynamically generated using javascript (imagine a jquery that calls a web service to get a list of items and renders them on the page)

My first thought was to use WebBrowser control to load the page. But it needs a GUI to host the web control so it's out of the question.

Can anyone suggest what else I can try? Is there a library that can parse a web page without having to be visible?

Answer (score 0):

Open up Google Chrome Developer Tools (press F12), and go to the network tab. There's a small button with a circle icon at the bottom left (Preserve log upon navigation) that you may want to click.

If you now browse to the page you want your tool to capture, Chrome will record all the HTTP requests made by the browser--including any XHR requests.

You should be able to use this to figure out how to form identical HTTP requests in your tool or script to retrieve the same information.

Answer (score 0):

there are various facilitates for parsing the web page you can use the 'HTML Agility pack ' to do same.
There is one more site where you will find the parser already designed the site is [black belt coder](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com)